# Installing linux on a macbook pro - boot broken

Tags: macos, ubuntu, boot, uefi

So I tried to install ubuntu 14.04 on my macbook pro (completely replacing OSX). I had refit installed, but not it seems gone. And every time I boot, the PC can't find any OS.

I tried using boot-repair with all the possible options, but it never fixed the boot.

I have the following partitions:

```
/dev/sda1 : EFI boot
/dev/sda2 : /
/dev/sda3 : swap
```

I tried installing refind using the `--root` option, but it didn't work, here is the output:

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/share/refind# mkdir /media/boot
root@ubuntu:/usr/share/refind# mount /dev/sda1 /media/boot/
root@ubuntu:/usr/share/refind# ./install.sh --root /media/boot/
Installing rEFInd on Linux....
ESP was found at /media/boot using vfat
Found rEFInd installation in /media/boot/EFI/refind; upgrading it.
Copied rEFInd binary files

Notice: Backed up existing icons directory as icons-backup.
Existing refind.conf file found; copying sample file as refind.conf-sample
to avoid overwriting your customizations.

Fatal: Couldn't open either sysfs or procfs directories for accessing EFI variables.
Try 'modprobe efivars' as root.
Installing it!

ALERT: There were problems running the efibootmgr program! You may need to
rename the refind_x64.efi binary to the default name (EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
on x86-64 systems or EFI/boot/bootia32.efi on x86 systems) to have it run!

Existing /media/boot//boot/refind_linux.conf found; not overwriting.

ALERT:
Installation has completed, but problems were detected. Review the output for
error messages and take corrective measures as necessary. You may need to
re-run this script or install manually before rEFInd will work.

root@ubuntu:/usr/share/refind#
```

Running `modprobe efivars` didn't change anything.

So right now I'm kinda lost: posting this from a liveCD, not really understanding why the MBP is not picking up the EFI boot correctly.

Comment: Did you use the EFI Ubuntu ISO? Daft question. But just making sure...

Comment: @BigChris yes I did, I wasn't even able to boot the live USB otherwise. Also, Ubuntu is the one who created the efi boot partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's fixed!**

After reading a little more the errors, I saw this:

```
ALERT: There were problems running the efibootmgr program! You may need to
rename the refind_x64.efi binary to the default name (EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
on x86-64 systems or EFI/boot/bootia32.efi on x86 systems) to have it run!
```

So I inspected the `/EFI/` folder, and found no `boot` folder in it.

```
# mkdir /media/boot/EFI/boot
# cp /media/boot/EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi /media/boot/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
```

This works! refind is kinda broken (no icon), but I can boot fine.

To restore the icons and have refind work correctly:

```
# cp -R /media/boot/EFI/refind/* /media/boot/EFI/boot/
```

Comment: You need to copy the rest of the `/media/boot/EFI/refind` directory tree to `/media/boot/EFI/boot` -- in particular, the `icons` subdirectory and `refind.conf` file.

Comment: Fantastic, a godsend.  On Debian Jessie (Testing), the base directory is /boot/efi/EFI, but following the steps above essentially worked.  (also, icons as Rod pointed out.)